# .htaccess Rewrite rule to include files

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to figure out the right rule for redirecting all url to files from one domain to another:

`oldsite.com/uploads/imagefile.png` to `newsite.com/uploads/imagefile.png`

All rules I tried have worked for links such as `oldsite.com/uploads/` which does get redirected to `newsite.com/uploads/` however, once I add a file to the path, I get a 404.

Here's one rule I tried:

`Redirect 301 /uploads http://www.newsite.com/uploads`

or

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ https://www.newsite.com/uploads/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: In which folder is your `.htaccess` located ? Is there any parent folder above `uploads` ?

Comment: the .htaccess is located right next to the index.html file - everything else is removed from the old domain.

Comment: Two possibilities your second rule didn't work: 1) htaccess files are not allowed (check your apache config) or 2) urls are not `/uploads/xxx` but `/parent/uploads/xxx` (I'm telling you this looking at your comment on answer below, because you're talking about WP and a parent `wp-content` folder

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ (www\.)?oldsite.com/uploads/$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/uploads/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can view this rule working here: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=cf237628-6307-5cd2-992c-5db8ffef8568

It checks for both variations of the URL (www / non-www) and then using `R=301` redirection, which is a permanent redirection to points to the new domain and correlating image file.

I'd advise changing this to `R=302` while testing, as this is a temporary redirect. Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

Comment: after adding this, the root `oldsite.com` is returning 500 and the link to a file `oldsite.com/uploads/imagefile.png` still 404 (this is a Wordpress site, btw - if of any help)

Comment: I tried that htaccess tester and it was always telling me the rules would work - if I actually try a redirect tester, or actually testing it myself - it would never work

Comment: It will be down to your server / another rule conflicting with it in your `.htaccess`. Do you have anything else in there?

Comment: nope - the oldsite is an empty site with 1 html file and the .htaccess file. This was an old domain used for a WP site. I am trying to redirect all links floating on Google (e.g. `/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/testfile.jpg`) to the new domain, where the files exist.

Comment: @Joe Your rule will never ever match since `%{HTTP_HOST}` only contains the domain name. The problem is elsewhere. Indeed, your answer brings nothing new from what OP initially tried